# How do I unit-test without launching app?

Tags: swift, xcode, unit-testing

Other day, I wrote an app without unit-test.
Now I need to upgrade my app version, so I need degrade check.
So I want write unit-test in my app.
But I can't do even very simple test code.

I wrote this code in unit-test.

```
func targetCode(num:Int)->Int{    
  return num * 2 
}

func testMyCode(){
  XCTAssertEqual(4, targetCode(2))
}
```

when I run testing, My app launch, and crash by "UIApplication.delegate must be used from main thread only"

I think my app use AppDelegate, so  I want way how to unit-test without launching app.

Comment: you should use a unit test target to test the app, not write the tests in the main target. Also, the unit tests will automatically launch the app, afaik there is no way around it.

Comment: Yeah even when you're running a unit test target, the app will always somehow run because it's the `host` application